# Reids Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, redis

Can any one list out the patterns for redis like as TDG (table data gateway)? Actually I tried with TDG, but I am not satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table data gateway describes an object being used as an interface or gateway to a table in a database. Redis alone would be the equivalent to the database store and so you would need an object, maybe created with ruby or php for example, to act as an interface to a key or group of keys within the redis dataset.

The closest model would be an object acting as an interface to a key holding a collection of data, such as a set or list.

Hope that helps.